# In listing page of users in the column of action want add a change_password link and its process of working

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel-backpack 4.0. want to add a password change link with a page and all the functionality with validation and all, to a listing of users like edit, in the Action column.

Comment: Hi @HMInt. Im not sure I quite understand the use case, perhaps you could explain in more detail?

Comment: Hello, @WesleySmith in my project there is a user management module, as an admin, i want to change the passwords of my all users from that listing page. how can i do that?

Comment: Hmm, are you wanting to change all their passwords at once, or individually? If individually, have you seen this plugin that adds a User CRUD with password change functionality built in? https://github.com/eduardoarandah/UserManager/

Comment: Yes individually. in that plugin password field is coming on the edit link, which is i don't want that way. what i want is a change password link on after edit link which will open a page with only 2 fields password and confirm the password, after the click on submit it will show notification password is changed, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit odd to want another page where you can update *only* the password when the package's built in user crud lets you update that, and all the other user fields. That said, assuming you have your reasons (and that I've understood the usage correctly), one approach would be to use the [users addon package](https://github.com/eduardoarandah/UserManager) suggested but then make a second CRUD controller for the user model that only supports the "update" operation and only allows editing the password.

#### NOTE

This is untested so there might be some minor issues to iron out, but the approach is sound.

Install and configure the [users addon package](https://github.com/eduardoarandah/UserManager). Then, create a second controller for users but edit such that only the "update" action is allowed and only the password and password confirmation fields are editable. We'll make the name and email read only so you can see who its for but cant edit those fields. You can make those fields hidden if you want, or remove them, but if you remove them, note that you'll need to create a custom request class and update the rules to not require those fields on submission.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Requests\CrudRequest;
use EduardoArandaH\UserManager\app\Http\Requests\UserStoreCrudRequest as StoreRequest;
use EduardoArandaH\UserManager\app\Http\Requests\UserUpdateCrudRequest as UpdateRequest;

class UserPasswordCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation { update as traitUpdate; }

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->crud->setModel(config('backpack.permissionmanager.models.user'));
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('User Password', 'User Passwords');
        $this->crud->setRoute(backpack_url('userPasswords'));
        $this->crud->denyAccess('create');
        $this->crud->denyAccess('list');
        $this->crud->denyAccess('delete');
        $this->crud->denyAccess('reorder');
        $this->crud->denyAccess('revisions');
    }

    public function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->addUserFields();
        $this->crud->setValidation(UpdateRequest::class);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in the database.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update()
    {
        $this->crud->setRequest($this->crud->validateRequest());
        $this->crud->setRequest($this->handlePasswordInput($this->crud->getRequest()));
        $this->crud->unsetValidation(); // validation has already been run
        return $this->traitUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * Handle password input fields.
     */
    protected function handlePasswordInput($request)
    {
        // Remove fields not present on the user.
        $request->request->remove('password_confirmation');
        $request->request->remove('roles_show');
        $request->request->remove('permissions_show');

        // Encrypt password if specified.
        if ($request->input('password')) {
            $request->request->set('password', Hash::make($request->input('password')));
        } else {
            $request->request->remove('password');
        }

        return $request;
    }

    protected function addUserFields()
    {
        $this->crud->addFields([
            [
                'name'  => 'name',
                'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.name'),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'attributes' => ['readonly' => 'readonly'],
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'email',
                'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.email'),
                'type'  => 'email',
                'attributes' => ['readonly' => 'readonly'],
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'password',
                'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.password'),
                'type'  => 'password',
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
                'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.password_confirmation'),
                'type'  => 'password',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Load the route for the new controller:

```
<?php

Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => ['web', backpack_middleware()],
], function () {
    Route::crud('userPasswords', 'UserPasswordCrudController');
});
```

Create a custom button at `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons/update_password.blade.php` with this content:

```
@if ($crud->hasAccess('update'))
    <!-- Single edit button -->
    <a href="{{ url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix').'/userPasswords/'.$entry->getKey().'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-link"><i class="la la-edit"></i>Edit Password</a>
@endif
```

Finally, in your normal user crud controller (or whatever controller you want the button in) add the button to the line stack in your controller's setupListOperation method:

```
public function setupListOperation()
{
    $this->crud->addButtonFromView('line', 'update_password', 'view', 'end');
    
    // ... normal setup code
}
```